# Setting Culture Info for Windows Forms Application

Tags: windows, forms, culture

I have packaged and deployed a Windows Forms application to our server. Now to my horror it is failing, which I realized is due to Regional and Language settings. The date format I am getting is in US format while the setting is for United Kingdom. This is causing my application to fail.

After searching a lot I am finding solutions for this which is done programatically. This will require me to package and deploy again which is a pain due to huge processes involved. As far as I am aware this is possible in a web application.

Is there a workaround for this without doing it programatically? May be through config?
Changing the Regional and Language Settings in Control Panel is not an option as other applications can fail. One question is that is it possible to set these for specific applications?

Server: Windows Server 2003

Thanks
 Nishant

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by specifying `System.Thread.CurrentCulture` in your code.